# Yaml-Cpp find out if value was quoted

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I'm reading in a yaml file with a big map which looks like this:

```
test_value: '123'
test_value2: 123
test_value3: 1.0
test_value4: true
test_value5: 'some information'
```

I can parse it to get the values but I want to know the type of the value. I have specified that a double is always written as a double and boolean are always true or false and also that strings have to be always quoted.

Now the problem is that if I want to read it out again with yaml-cpp I don't get the '123' but rather 123 which I then interpret as a int rather then the string it should be.

Is there any possibility that I overlooked to figure out if there where some quotes around it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to figure out if it quoted. In a node there is a tag which you can get with node.Tag()  this will in my usecase return me a ! or a ?  since the ! is only returned on a former string it can be destingueshed like this.